# How to decrease audio volume while looping in javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I want to control audio volume by decreasing it while function loop, but my below code doesn't seems to work.

```
var count = 0;
var rotate= 5;
var saudio = $("#saudio").get(0);

function tryitnow(){
count++;
saudio.volume = parseInt(saudio.volume)- parseInt(0.1); 
  if (count != rotate) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      tryitnow()
    }, 1000);

  }
}
```

Comment: `HTMLMediaElement.volume` and `0.1` are already numbers, `parseInt()` is not necessary

Comment: @guest271314 okay i just removed it and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt(0.1);` will return `0` because it will round the float `0.1` so each time you are reducing the volume by `0`

You don't need to `parseInt(saudio.volume)` since it's already a number too.

So this should work

```
var count = 0;
var rotate = 5;
var saudio = $("#saudio").get(0);

function tryitnow() {
  count++;
  saudio.volume = saudio.volume - 0.1;
  if (count != rotate) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      tryitnow()
    }, 1000);

  }
}
```